# F# slicing array by indices array

Tags: f#

How can I overload .[] for F# array to slice an array based on an arbitrary index array?

For example:

```
let x = [|1..10|]; 
let indx = [|4;1|];
```

although

```
[| for i in indx ->x.[i]|]
```

would work, it would be nicer to be able using `x.[indx]` directly.

Comment: Your example does not perform *slicing* - it only retrieves different elements of the array. Slicing would f.ex. be `x.[2..6]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always write an F# extension method to get close on the syntax

```
let a = [| 1..10 |]
let idx = [|4;1|]

type 'T ``[]`` with   //'
    member this.Slice(indices:int array) =
        [| for i in indices -> this.[i] |]

printfn "%A" (a.Slice idx)
```

but since arrays already have an indexer it doesn't appear there's a way to overload/change it.